# Espresso - how can you perform an OR ( || ) check?

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I need only one of these two espresso checks to pass. How can I achieve this? If either of these `ViewAssertion`s pass, I will be happy.

```
    onView(withId(R.id.mainview))
            .check(

                    matches(not(isDisplayed()))
            )
```

or

```
    onView(withId(R.id.mainview))
            .check(

                    doesNotExist()
            )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't the best method but it'll work. Ideally you should use a custom view matcher... but we're all lazy.

```
try {
  // See if view is displayed
  onView(withId(R.id.mainview))
          .check(
                  matches(not(isDisplayed()))
          );
}
catch (NoMatchingViewException e){
  // Otherwise check it doesn't exist
  onView(withId(R.id.mainview))
          .check(
                  doesNotExist()
          );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your only option is a custom matcher.